# Неизвестная ошибка при создании собственной функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Писал свою функцию для присвоения свойств к псевдоэлементам и заметил неведомую ошибку. Присваивание свойств идёт через добавления строк в styleSheet.

Когда в третьем случае вызываю функцию, почему то красится в синий первый элемент, хотя `color` для него я не ставил.

```js
(function() {
  var setPseudoElement = function(parameters) {
    for (var element of parameters.elements.get()) {
      if (!element.pseudoElements) element.pseudoElements = {
        styleSheet: null,
        before: {
          index: null,
          properties: null
        },
        after: {
          index: null,
          properties: null
        }
      };

      var selector = (function() {
        if (element.id) {
          return '#' + element.id + '::' + parameters.pseudoElement;
        } else {
          var parentsList = $(element).parents().map(function() {
            return this.tagName.toLowerCase();
          }).get().reverse().join(' > ') + ' > ' + element.tagName.toLowerCase();

          var elementClass = element.classList.length ? '.' + $(element.classList).get().join('.') : '';

          var elementAttributes = element.hasAttributes() ? $(element.attributes).get().map(function(className) {
            return className.nodeName !== 'class' ? className.nodeValue ? '[' + className.nodeName + '="' + className.nodeValue + '"]' : '[' + className.nodeName + '"]' : '';
          }).join('') : '';

          var elementNthChild = ':nth-child(' + ($(element).index() + 1) + ')';

          return parentsList + elementClass + elementAttributes + elementNthChild + '::' + parameters.pseudoElement;
        };
      })();

      if (!element.pseudoElements.styleSheet) {
        if (document.styleSheets[0]) {
          element.pseudoElements.styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
        } else {
          var styleSheet = document.createElement('style');

          document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);
          element.pseudoElements.styleSheet = styleSheet.sheet;
        };
      };

      if (element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties !== null && element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index !== null) {
        element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.deleteRule(element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index);
      };

      if (typeof parameters.argument === 'object') {
        if (!element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties && !element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index) {
          var newIndex = element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.rules.length || element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.cssRules.length || element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.length;

          element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index = newIndex;
          element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties = parameters.argument;
        };

        var properties = '';

        for (var property in parameters.argument) {
          element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[property] = parameters.argument[property];
        };

        for (var property in element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties) {
          properties += property + ': ' + element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[property] + ' !important; ';
        };

        element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.addRule(selector, properties, element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index);
      } else if (parameters.argument !== undefined && parameters.property !== undefined) {

      } else if (parameters.argument !== undefined && parameters.property === undefined) {

      } else {
        console.error('Invalid values!');
        return false;
      };
    };
  };

  $.fn.cssBefore = function(argument, property) {
    setPseudoElement({
      elements: this,
      pseudoElement: 'before',
      argument: argument,
      property: property
    });
  };
})();

$(function() {
  // Случай 1
  $('.el0').cssBefore({
    'content': '"Новый \'before\'"',
    'color': 'green'
  });
  // Случай 2
  $('.el1').cssBefore({
    'content': '"Новый \'before\' №2"',
    'color': 'blue'
  });
  // Случай 3
  $('.el0').cssBefore({
    'content': '"Новый \'before\' №3"'
  });
});
```

```css
.element {
  width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.element:before {
  content: "Старый 'before'";
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element el0" name="MyName"></div>
<div class="element el0 el1" id="elem"></div>
<div>
  <div class="element el1"></div>
</div>
```

Почему в третьем случае красится в синий первый элемент? Как это исправить?

---

**UPDATA:**

Если выводить в консоль значения элементов после каждого присваивания, то выходят очень странные значения:

```js
(function () {
    var i = 1;

    var setPseudoElement = function (parameters) {
        for (var element of parameters.elements.get()) {
            if (!element.pseudoElements) element.pseudoElements = {styleSheet: null, before: {index: null, properties: null}, after: {index: null, properties: null}};
            
            var selector = (function () {
                if (element.id) {
                    return '#' + element.id + '::' + parameters.pseudoElement;
                } else {
                    var parentsList = $(element).parents().map(function () {
                        return this.tagName.toLowerCase();
                    }).get().reverse().join(' > ') + ' > ' + element.tagName.toLowerCase();

                    var elementClass = element.classList.length ? '.' + $(element.classList).get().join('.') : '';

                    var elementAttributes = element.hasAttributes() ? $(element.attributes).get().map(function (className) {
                        return className.nodeName !== 'class' ? className.nodeValue ? '[' + className.nodeName + '="' + className.nodeValue + '"]' : '[' + className.nodeName + '"]' : '';
                    }).join('') : '';

                    var elementNthChild = ':nth-child(' + ($(element).index() + 1) + ')';

                    return parentsList + elementClass + elementAttributes + elementNthChild + '::' + parameters.pseudoElement;
                };
            })();

            if (!element.pseudoElements.styleSheet) {
                if (document.styleSheets[0]) {
                    element.pseudoElements.styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
                } else {
                    var styleSheet = document.createElement('style');

                    document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);
                    element.pseudoElements.styleSheet = styleSheet.sheet;
                };
            };

            if (element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties !== null && element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index !== null) {
                element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.deleteRule(element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index);
            };

            if (typeof parameters.argument === 'object') {
                if (!element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties && !element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index) {
                    var newIndex = element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.rules.length || element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.cssRules.length ||  element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.length;

                    element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index = newIndex;
                    element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties = parameters.argument;
                };

                var properties = '';

                for (var property in parameters.argument) {
                    element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[property] = parameters.argument[property];
                };

                for (var property in element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties) {
                    properties += property + ': ' + element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[property] + ' !important; ';
                };

                element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.addRule(selector, properties, element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index);
            
                console.log('Номер запуска: ' + Math.round(i / 2) + '; Номер присваивания элементу: ' + i);
                console.log({
                    'Элемент 1': $('.el0:not(.el1)').get(0).pseudoElements,
                    'Элемент 2': $('.el0.el1').get(0).pseudoElements,
                    'Элемент 3': $('.el1:not(.el0)').get(0).pseudoElements
                });
                i++;
            } else if (parameters.argument !== undefined && parameters.property !== undefined) {

            } else if (parameters.argument !== undefined && parameters.property === undefined) {

            } else {
                console.error('Invalid values!');
                return false;
            };
        };
    };

    $.fn.cssBefore = function (argument, property) {
        setPseudoElement ({
            elements: this, 
            pseudoElement: 'before', 
            argument: argument, 
            property: property
        });
    };
})();

$(function() {
  // Случай 1
  $('.el0').cssBefore({
    'content': '"Новый \'before\'"',
    'color': 'green'
  });
  // Случай 2
  $('.el1').cssBefore({
    'content': '"Новый \'before\' №2"',
    'color': 'blue'
  });
  // Случай 3
  $('.el0').cssBefore({
    'content': '"Новый \'before\' №3"'
  });
});
```

```css
.element {
  width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.element:before {
  content: "Старый 'before'";
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element el0" name="MyName"></div>
<div class="element el0 el1" id="elem"></div>
<div>
  <div class="element el1"></div>
</div>
```

Если смотреть в консоль, то уже при первом вызове функции, элемент №1 имеет синий цвет и содержимое №3

Comment: Потому что вы добавили ему стиль html > body > div:nth-child(4)::before     color: blue;

Comment: @Vitalii, всё верно. Ведь `:nth-child(1)` - это элемент `script`

Comment: Продебажьте код в консоле, найдете в чем ошибка.

Comment: @Yuri ну так и проведи **debugging (отладку)** на предмет исправления этой ошибки, а не просто смотри в консоль))

Comment: добавь хотя бы описание, что твой код делает

Comment: @Grundy, А по коду этого не видно? Ну ладно

Comment: @Grundy, редактирует css указанного pseudo элемента вроде. Хоть без бутылки и не понять

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, _Хоть без бутылки и не понять_ - именно поэтому и должно было быть описание в вопросе :-)

Comment: @Grundy, добавил...

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465485

Comment: @Yuri Вроде бы есть ответ, обновил свой ответ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Думаю что я нашел проблему:

```
element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties = parameters.argument;
```

где `parameters.argument` — это объект.
Когда мы делаем первый проход, мы задаем его для первого и второго элемента. 
Когда на втором проходе мы меняем его для второго случая, он меняется и для первого тоже.

И вот пруф и решение

```
element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties = Object.assign({}, parameters.argument);
```

Comment: Но я не добавлял синий цвет в параметры первого элемента... Там должен быть зелёный

Comment: Он в before лежит... Сейчас раскопаем откуда он там взялся.

Comment: Тут и не понятно :)

Comment: Вот, говорил же, что явно как-то на `parameters ` завязано. Браво

Comment: собственно, достаточно `.properties = {}`, потому что следом идет цикл, в котором копируются свойства из arguments

Comment: Ты гений! Спасибо!

Comment: 3 дня мучений. А я даже не подумал про это

Comment: @Yuri Давно я так не дебажил, спасибо за весело проведенное время :)

Comment: @Vitalii, если не против, награду через неделю присвою. Так и тебе больше плюсов наставят и мне :)

Comment: @Yuri без проблем :)

Comment: @Vitalii, добавь ответ и на enSO, чтобы и там знали. А то так и не ответили :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465485/unknown-error-when-creating-own-function

Comment: @Yuri отличная идея, ответил и там. Спасибо, было весело)

Comment: @Vitalii, мне тоже было весело :)

Comment: @Vitalii, если не сложно, перейди в мой чат. Хочу поговорить. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52027/communication-with-the-yuri

Comment: @Yuri я тут но не долго

Answer (score 6):

Вот так поведение будет ожидаемым Вами.
В чем изначально был подвох - пока разбираюсь, дополню в течении получаса.
setTimeoutы стоят для удобства дебага, если что.
Товарищи, хоть убейте, я не понимаю, почему оно работает и что вообще изначально не так.
Смущает проскальзывание в теле цикла элемента `parameters`, так как, по логике, его внутри цикла быть не должно, работа ведется с конкретным `element`, но скорее всего, просто я не знаю `jquery`.

```js
(function() {
  var i = 1;

  var setPseudoElement = function(parameters) {
    for (var element of parameters.elements.get()) {
     if (!element.pseudoElements){ element.pseudoElements = {
        styleSheet: null,
        before: {
          index: null,
          properties: null
        },
        after: {
          index: null,
          properties: null
        }
      };}
     if (element.pseudoElements) {
        element.pseudoElements.before.properties = null;
        element.pseudoElements.before.index = null;
      }
  

      var selector = (function() {
        if (element.id) {
          return '#' + element.id + '::' + parameters.pseudoElement;
        } else {
          var parentsList = $(element).parents().map(function() {
            return this.tagName.toLowerCase();
          }).get().reverse().join(' > ') + ' > ' + element.tagName.toLowerCase();

          var elementClass = element.classList.length ? '.' + $(element.classList).get().join('.') : '';

          var elementAttributes = element.hasAttributes() ? $(element.attributes).get().map(function(className) {
            return className.nodeName !== 'class' ? className.nodeValue ? '[' + className.nodeName + '="' + className.nodeValue + '"]' : '[' + className.nodeName + '"]' : '';
          }).join('') : '';

          var elementNthChild = ':nth-child(' + ($(element).index() + 1) + ')';

          return parentsList + elementClass + elementAttributes + elementNthChild + '::' + parameters.pseudoElement;
        };
      })();

      if (!element.pseudoElements.styleSheet) {
        if (document.styleSheets[0]) {
          element.pseudoElements.styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
        } else {
          var styleSheet = document.createElement('style');

          document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);
          element.pseudoElements.styleSheet = styleSheet.sheet;
        };
      };

      if (element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties !== null && element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index !== null) {
        element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.deleteRule(element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index);
      };

      if (typeof parameters.argument === 'object') {
        if (!element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties && !element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index) {
          var newIndex = element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.rules.length || element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.cssRules.length || element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.length;

          element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index = newIndex;
          element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties = parameters.argument;
        };

        var properties = '';

        for (var property in parameters.argument) {
          element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[property] = parameters.argument[property];
        };

        for (var property in element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties) {
          properties += property + ': ' + element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].properties[property] + ' !important; ';
        };

        element.pseudoElements.styleSheet.addRule(selector, properties, element.pseudoElements[parameters.pseudoElement].index);

        console.log('Номер запуска: ' + Math.round(i / 2) + '; Номер присваивания элементу: ' + i);
        console.log({
          'Элемент 1': $('.el0:not(.el1)').get(0).pseudoElements,
          'Элемент 2': $('.el0.el1').get(0).pseudoElements,
          'Элемент 3': $('.el1:not(.el0)').get(0).pseudoElements
        });
        i++;
      } else if (parameters.argument !== undefined && parameters.property !== undefined) {

      } else if (parameters.argument !== undefined && parameters.property === undefined) {

      } else {
        console.error('Invalid values!');
        return false;
      };
    };
  };

  $.fn.cssBefore = function(argument, property) {
    setPseudoElement({
      elements: this,
      pseudoElement: 'before',
      argument: argument,
      property: property
    });
  };
})();

$(function() {
  // Случай 1
  $('.el0').cssBefore({
    'content': '"Новый \'before\'"',
    'color': 'green'
  });
  setTimeout(() => {
  // Случай 2
  $('.el1').cssBefore({
    'content': '"Новый \'before\' №2"',
    'color': 'blue'
  });
  }, 3000);
  // Случай 3
  setTimeout(() => {
  $('.el0').cssBefore({
    'content': '"Новый \'before\' №3"'
  });}, 6000);
});
```

```css
.element {
  width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.element:before {
  content: "Старый 'before'";
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element el0" name="MyName"></div>
<div class="element el0 el1" id="elem"></div>
<div>
  <div class="element el1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Честно, думал такого не бывает. Сижу, туплю..

Comment: Если честно, я тоже не пойму, почему ваш ответ работает. Сам сижу понять не могу

Comment: Если никто так и не напишет почему, то репутация ваша

Comment: @Yuri, но он работает, мне не показалось? Вы потестили на других примерах?

Comment: Я потестил в нескольких случаях и во всех вариантах работает. Интересно, конечно

Comment: Я где-то повыше писал, что без бутылки не разберешься. Кажется, нужна вторая. @Grundy, Вы тоже висите?

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, ошибка в расшаривании общего stylesheet. Добавь пояснение что именно ты поменял

Comment: @Grundy, ну это вроде как понятно на уровне идеи. Примерно из этих соображений я и сделал сбрасывание стилей в начале постоянным. Где конкретно не очень понятно

Comment: @Yuri там в один из моментов мы пишем в чужой стайлшит но обновляется стили первого элемента. Как это происходит я пока понять не могу.

Comment: Тут в ответе минус есть: не удаляются старые свойства с stylesheet и там накапливается много строк со свойствами

Comment: @Yuri, я конкретизировал свой фикс до двух строк. Уже мотодом подбора. Jquery, правда, не знаю, сейчас вот читаю мануалы и думаю. МОжет наведет Вас на мысль))

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko интересно, какого хрена происходит? :D

Comment: @Yuri, мы программируем на javascript с использованием jquery. Все норм

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, как можно заметить, функций Jqeury тут по минимуму и я JQuery нигде в основном функционале не использовал

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, ответ выше найден!

Comment: @Yuri я уже порадовался за всех).

Comment: © .. Смущает проскальзывание в теле цикла элемента parameters, так как, по логике, его внутри цикла быть не должно, работа ведется с конкретным element..

вы задаете в параметрах цикла ...var property in parameters.argument..., все правильно и получается..